# Storing higherarchy of DOM elements in JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, html, dom

### Endless Variables

Often I find myself assigning numerous DOM elements to a list variables, and naming them gets increasingly difficult as things grow more complex.

```
const header = document.querySelector('header')
const headerWrapper = header.querySelector('.header-wrapper')
const headerH1 = headerWrapper.querySelector('h1')
const headerH2 = headerWrapper.querySelector('h2')
// etc...
```

### Object Notation

It occurred to me try referencing the DOM hierarchy using Objects instead and came up with something like this:

```
// assign DOM elements to object properties
const homePage = {
    headerContainer: document.querySelector('header'),
    headerWrapper: document.querySelector('header>.header-wrapper'),
    header: {
        h1: document.querySelector('header>.header-wrapper>h1'),
        h2: document.querySelector('header>.header-wrapper>h2'),
    }
}
// update element content
homePage.header.h1.innerText = "New Header Text"
```

This method is flawed however:

- Parent nodes must be given unique keys to reference directly
- Objects can't refer to themselves until they have been initialized, so I can't have `h1: this.headerContainer.querySelector('h1')`

Instead of relying on `headerContainer` it would be better to have `homePage.header`, as well as the h1 tag within that container with `homePage.header.h1` but I'm not sure if that's possible with JavaScript/JSON.... to my mind it would be something like this:

```
// pseudocode
const homePage = {
    header: 
        document.querySelector('header'),
        {
            h1: this.header.querySelector('h1'),
            h2: this.header.querySelector('h2'),
        }
}

// update element content
homePage.header.h1.innerText = "Cleaner Syntax"
```

Is there some other means of doing this? Using Classes or Object Constructors perhaps?

Edit 1:

### Solution: Using Classes

I think what I want to work out is how to store elements as an attribute of another element or object property, and I think I have worked out how to do that using Classes:

```js
class Page {
    constructor(body = document.querySelector('body')) {
        this.header = body.querySelector('header')
        this.header.h1 = this.header.querySelector('h1')
    }
}

const homePage = new Page()
homePage.header.style.backgroundColor='yellow'
homePage.header.h1.textContent = "Hello World"
```

Comment: use `body.onload`

Comment: Why do you need the object instead of just referring directly to the elements as needed?

Comment: like I said, it gets harder to name things the more complex the page gets, so I was hoping to find a neater way of doing it. I guess I am hoping to better understand the limitations of this language and explore features I might be unaware of.

Comment: Using Objects will also mean VS Code will help you out a bit with tooltips, listing the object properties